# Partitions with each part dividing the original number

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

I have a question on partitions that I have not seen being discussed. It deals with those related to divisors.

My definition of partitions I am working with is as follow: a sequence of weakly decreasing positive integers $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots)$ is a partition of $n$ if $\sum_i \lambda_i=n$.

**My question is:** Is there any way to enumerate the number of partitions $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots)$ of $n$ such that each $\lambda_i$ is a divisor of $n$? If not, is there any asymptotic estimates for this, or perhaps a good method to attack this problem?

This problem came up because I was trying to understand the $n$-torsion elements of the symmetric group $S_n$.

Note: I have almost no experience with partition numbers and partitions functions.

Comment: Asymptotic estimates will of course depend delicately on the prime factorization of $n$. Would you be happy with a result averaged over many large values of $n$ or are you interested in particular large values of $n$?

Comment: OEIS entry: https://oeis.org/A018818